# from java package how about in python?

Tags: python

I have search the ways that how can I define some thing like this in python OOP ways:

**java:**

```
package project.work;
public interface IWork
{
    public void input();
    public void display();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't really have interfaces as separate from classes. You can use the [`abc`](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html) module to get a similar effect. Discussion on that method and on some others is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382945/abstract-methods-in-python).

Answer (score -1):

Since python is a dynamically typed language it would seem silly to try this. The notion of interfaces really only makes sense in a statically typed language, in python you call a method on an object and find out at runtime if the object given actually implements the method.