# How to call subclass methods in a superclass in Python

Tags: python

I want to know how to call subclass methods in the superclass.

Comment: Can you be more explicit with your question.

Answer (score 20):

I believe this is a pattern used often.

```
class A(object):
    def x(self):
        self.y()

    def y(self):
        print('default behavior')


class B(A):
    def y(self):
        print('Child B behavior')

class C(A):
    def z(self):
        pass

>>>B().x()
Child B behavior
>>>C().x()
default behavior
```

It is sort of like an abstract class, but provides default behavior. Can't remember the name of the pattern off the top of my head though.

Comment: Using C++ terminology it'd just be polymorphism. But with Python that's true for everything...

Answer (score 8):

The point behind a subclass is that it *extends* and *alters* the behaviour of the superclass. The superclass can't know *how*  a subclass will extend it.

**Edit:** But it is well possible that the superclass knows, *that* the subclass will extend it. Not sure, if this is good design, though.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I've just tried:

```
class A(object):
    def x(self): 
        print self.y()

class B(A):
    def y(self): 
        return 1

>>> B().x()
1
```

So unless you had some specific problem, just call a method from the subclass in the base class and it should just work.

Comment: I wonder why somebody wants to do this. Why do I want to write `A` in a way that i nows in advance how `B` will extend it?

Comment: @Tichodroma: Yeah, there's some code smell here. But maybe it's e.g. the lecturer of the OP who's out of sync with reality ;) ?

Comment: @Tichodroma maybe you don't know it? Let `A` be a base class which can be extended in, say, 3 or 4 ways. It doesn't know how these are implemented, only which signature they provide. I've seen such things often, e.g. in `MySQLdb`.

Comment: Am I missing somtehing but both of this and glglgl answer are calling superclass methods from subclass which is not what OP asked for?

Comment: Thank you very much...that's exactly what i wanted

Comment: @zta1987: Great, then maybe you can accept one of the answers ;) ?

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, you're missing something. ;-) Class A (superclass) is calling y() in class B (subclass), which is what OP asked about.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question. As you don't provide example code, I'll just show the easiest example:

```
class A(object):
   def meth1(self, a):
       self.meth2(a, a*a)

class B(A):
   def meth2(self, a, b):
       return b / a

b = B()
b.meth1(10)
```

Comment: Where does `a` come from? Where the method `meth`?

Comment: @Tichodroma Sorry, my fault. Should think while writing ;-) Corrected now.

Comment: What if the classes are in separate modules?

i.e.
file2.py

    import file1
    class TestCase(file1.TestBase):

        def execute(self):
            self.pass()

file1.py

    class TestBase:
        
        def pass(self):
            print "PASS"

    testBase = TestBase()
    testBase.execute()

Comment: @ThePracticalOne Hard to read, but in your case, `file2.py` is not used at all. If you do `testcase = TestCase()` and `testcase.execute()`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to using abstract methods. The parent class defines methods that the subclass should implement and the parent class knows that these methods will be implemented. Similar structures exist for example in Java.

Using these in Python is discussed here well: [Abstract methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382945/abstract-methods-in-python)