# Python Metaclass : Understanding the 'with_metaclass()'

Tags: python, metaclass, six-python

I want to ask what the `with_metaclass()` call means in the definition of a class.

E.g.:

```
class Foo(with_metaclass(Cls1, Cls2)):
```

- Is it a special case where a class inherits from a metaclass?
- Is the new class a metaclass, too?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

[`with_metaclass()`](https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.with_metaclass) is a utility class factory function provided by the [`six` library](https://six.readthedocs.io/) to make it easier to develop code for both Python 2 and 3.

It uses a little sleight of hand (see below) with a temporary metaclass, to attach a metaclass to a regular class in a way that's cross-compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Quoting from the documentation:

> Create a new class with base class base and metaclass metaclass. This is designed to be used in class declarations like this:
>
> ```
> from six import with_metaclass
>    
> class Meta(type):
>     pass
>
> class Base(object):
>     pass
>
> class MyClass(with_metaclass(Meta, Base)):
>     pass
> ```

This is needed because the syntax to attach a metaclass changed between Python 2 and 3:

Python 2:

```
class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
```

Python 3:

```
class MyClass(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

The `with_metaclass()` function makes use of the fact that metaclasses are a) inherited by subclasses, and b) a metaclass can be used to generate new classes and c) when you subclass from a base class with a metaclass, creating the actual subclass object is delegated to the metaclass. It effectively creates a new, temporary base class with a temporary `metaclass` metaclass that, when used to create the subclass *swaps out* the temporary base class and metaclass combo with the metaclass of your choice:

```
def with_metaclass(meta, *bases):
    """Create a base class with a metaclass."""
    # This requires a bit of explanation: the basic idea is to make a dummy
    # metaclass for one level of class instantiation that replaces itself with
    # the actual metaclass.
    class metaclass(type):

        def __new__(cls, name, this_bases, d):
            return meta(name, bases, d)

        @classmethod
        def __prepare__(cls, name, this_bases):
            return meta.__prepare__(name, bases)
    return type.__new__(metaclass, 'temporary_class', (), {})
```

Breaking the above down:

- `type.__new__(metaclass, 'temporary_class', (), {})` uses the `metaclass` metaclass to create a new class object named `temporary_class` that is entirely empty otherwise. `type.__new__(metaclass, ...)` is used instead of `metaclass(...)` to avoid using the special `metaclass.__new__()` implementation that is needed for the slight of hand in a next step to work.
- In Python 3 only, when `temporary_class` is used as a base class, Python first calls `metaclass.__prepare__()` (passing in the derived class name, `(temporary_class,)` as the `this_bases` argument. The *intended* metaclass `meta` is then used to call `meta.__prepare__()`, ignoring `this_bases` and passing in the `bases` argument.
- next, after using the return value of `metaclass.__prepare__()` as the base namespace for the class attributes (or just using a plain dictionary when on Python 2), Python calls `metaclass.__new__()` to create the actual class. This is again passed `(temporary_class,)` as the `this_bases` tuple, but the code above ignores this and uses `bases` instead, calling on `meta(name, bases, d)` to create the new derived class.

As a result, using `with_metaclass()` gives you a new class object *with no additional base classes*:

```
>>> class FooMeta(type): pass
...
>>> with_metaclass(FooMeta)  # returns a temporary_class object
<class '__main__.temporary_class'>
>>> type(with_metaclass(FooMeta))  # which has a custom metaclass
<class '__main__.metaclass'>
>>> class Foo(with_metaclass(FooMeta)): pass
...
>>> Foo.__mro__  # no extra base classes
(<class '__main__.Foo'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> type(Foo) # correct metaclass
<class '__main__.FooMeta'>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, in six, the syntax (to match the behaviour of python 2 and 3 above): `class MyClass(with_metaclass(Meta, object)): pass` (where the object is optional).

Comment: If you don't want the `Base` class in your hierarchy, you can just do `MyClass = with_metaclass(Meta, MyClass)` after declaring `MyClass`, right?  This has the same caveats as the `add_metaclass` solution below I think (double class creation).

Comment: @DylanYoung: You don't need to bother. `with_metaclass()` was updated about a year after I wrote this answer to avoid having an extra class in the class inheritance hierarchy. A temporary class is still created, but only to intercept the class factory procedure.

Answer (score 28):

**UPDATE**: the `six.with_metaclass()` function has since been patched with a decorator variant, i.e. `@six.add_metaclass()`.  This update fixes some mro issues related to the base objects.  The new decorator would be applied as follows:

```
import six

@six.add_metaclass(Meta)
class MyClass(Base):
    pass
```

[Here are the patch notes](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/pull-requests/12/add-patch_with_metaclass-which-provides-a/diff) and [here is a similar, detailed example and explanation](http://www.zopatista.com/python/2014/03/14/cross-python-metaclasses/) for using a decorator alternative.

Comment: Thanks! This does not have issues with `isinstance` unlike every other way to have Py2/3 compatible metaclasses.

Comment: The decorator only works in certain scenarios in my experience, since it modifies/copies the class after creation, whereas the whole point of a metaclass is to determine how the class is created.   I forget what the exact errors were, but it was a pain; I would avoid it.

Comment: @pylang Thanks for the tip! I wish I could remember the trouble I was having.  If I encounter it again,  I'll file a bug report.

Comment: @pylang In general though, I don't think these problems can really be solved.  The fact is that a class decorator runs *after* a class is created.  That means any class with side-effects on creation will trigger those side-effects *twice*. If you think it's solvable using a class decorator approach, I'd love to hear how.  In case it helps, I think I came across the error creating a `ProxyModelBase` metaclass in Django.

Comment: @pylang In fact, this is mentioned right in the patch notes: "This is pretty nice. It does have the slightly non-intuitive effect that the class is created without the metaclass first. This might cause problems if the parent has a metaclass that is a superclass of the metaclass used with the decorator. That's also quite rare, so it can probably be ignored."

Comment: Considering this error (part of the python language design) "metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases", I'm not sure why the reviewer thinks this should be "quite rare"