# How to make a Python 2.x AND 3.x abstract base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, python-2.x

In Python 3 they're written like

```
from abc import ABCMeta 

class MyAbstractBaseClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo():
        pass
```

in Python 2 they're written like

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class MyAbstractBaseClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def foo():
        pass
```

But the `metaclass=ABCMeta` from Python 3 causes a `SyntaxError` in Python 2, and the `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta` line from Python 2 has no effect in Python 3 (it's possible to instantiate a subclass without those abstract methods defined).

So is there a way of doing this in both Python 2.x and 3.x?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513821/python-metaclass-understanding-the-with-metaclass).  The easy answer is to use the `with_metaclass` function from the `six` library.  The hard answer is to reimplement that function yourself.

Comment: Ah, thanks and apologies for dupe. I read 6 questions about abstract base classes but failed to seek the generalised version of the problem :) Ended up using the similar `six.add_metaclass`