# Check if a function raises NotImplementedError before calling it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have the following simplified scheme:

```
class NetworkAnalyzer(object):
    def __init__(self):
       print('is _score_funct implemented?')

    @staticmethod
    def _score_funct(network):
        raise NotImplementedError

class LS(NetworkAnalyzer):
    @staticmethod
    def _score_funct(network):
        return network
```

and I am looking for what I should use instead of `print('is _score_funct implemented?')` in order to figure out if a subclass has already implemented `_score_funct(network)` or not.

*Note: If there is a more pythonic/conventional way of structuring the code, I would also appreciate its mention. The reason I defined it this way is, some NetworkAnalyzer subclasses have _score_funct in their definition, and the ones that dont have it will have different initialization of variables although they will have the same structure*

Comment: abstract methods? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382945/abstract-methods-in-python

Comment: Well you could take a look at the AST and look if there is only a single raise statement and the only constant is `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: I would suggest you figure out the minimal behavior for each subclass and turn that into an abstract base class. See [the abc docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) . Research [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56860/2958070) .

Comment: Why not just _not_ implement the function in the base class and in `__init__` use `getattr()` and `callable()` to check if it exists and can be called?

Comment: I havent used abstract methods as I had little understanding of metaclasses. I will read the documentation to have it more conventional. By then, I have tried @Jean-FrançoisFabre's answer and it works

Comment: I've answered with something unrelated to abstract methods.

Comment: @Attie because almost all subclasses of NetworkAnalyzer have this function(except very few) and I want it to be clear in the class definition, in case someone adds another subclass and forgets to specify this critical score function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an abstract base class and you won't be able to instantiate the class unless it implements all of the abstract methods:

```
import abc

class NetworkAnalyzerInterface(abc.ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _score_funct(network):
        pass

class NetworkAnalyzer(NetworkAnalyzerInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class LS(NetworkAnalyzer):
    @staticmethod
    def _score_funct(network):
        return network

class Bad(NetworkAnalyzer):
    pass

ls = LS()   # Ok
b = Bad()   # raises TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Bad with abstract methods _score_funct
```

Comment: Do I need the NetworkAnalyzerInterface in this example by any conventional reason or can I just bypass it by `NetworkAnalyzer(abc.ABC)`

Comment: You can probably just make NetworkAnalyzer itself the abstract class in this case. I would just prefer to keep interface and implementation code separate although in the example I ended up with there's no implementation code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a metaclass/class specialist but here's a method that works in your simple case (not sure it works as-is in a complex/nested class namespace):

To check if the method was overridden, you could try a `getattr` on the function name, then check the qualified name (class part is enough using string partitionning):

```
class NetworkAnalyzer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        funcname = "_score_funct"
        d = getattr(self,funcname)
        print(d.__qualname__.partition(".")[0] == self.__class__.__name__)
```

if `_score_funct` is defined in `LS`, `d.__qualname__` is `LS._score_funct`, else it's `NetworkAnalyzer._score_funct`.

That works if the method is implemented at `LS` class level. Else you could replace by:

```
d.__qualname__.partition(".")[0] != "NetworkAnalyzer"
```

Of course if the method is overridden with some code which raises an `NotImplementedError`, that won't work... This method doesn't inspect methods code (which is hazardous anyway)